# Settings default parameter values with XML values

Tags: powershell

I read somewhere that the param section must be the very first thing that appears in a script or function so this is what I have come up with in order to set the default values of each of the params. Yes, it is unorthodox, but it works.

```
Param (
    [Xml]$xmlObj = (Get-Content "Download-VBK_config.xml"),
    [String]$dlFrom = $xmlObj.Configuration.Download.From,
    [String]$dlTo = $xmlObj.Configuration.Download.To,
    [String]$exTo = $xmlObj.Configuration.Extract.To
)
```

However, is there a better way I could go about setting a param's default value by loading values from an XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the parameters without default values, then look at the `$PSBoundParameters` variable to see what parameters were passed in, and fill the ones in that we're not passed.

```
Param(
    [string]$Param1,
    [string]$Param2)
[xml]$defaults =Get-Content file.xml
if(!$PSboundParameters.ContainsKey("Param1"))
{
    $Param1 = $defaults.Configuration.Defaults.Param1
}
```